Can't install Reaper on Ubuntu 24
** EDIT **
Didn't get it to work, even with all the help I got. Uninstalled and removed all folders. Extracted tar and now it works. Things must have gotten mixed up.
I am migrating my music production to beeing all linux, witch is not easy. I am having trouble installing Reaper for some reason and I can't figure out why!

I have followed several instructions for installation through Terminal. Including dependencies - for example this https://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-to-install-reaper-on-ubuntu-studio-20-04/ and this https://gist.github.com/wcoastsands/406bd892465a2334f4eff89204149451 for example.
I have also ran the install-reaper.sh file included in the package through Terminal.
I have read the readme file.
I have Ubuntu Studio installed on my system through the Ubuntu Studio installer so all the audio stuff should be there
I have the icon in the apps menu but it won't start when I press it
I have successfully installed Reaper before on a far inferior computer.

I have recently wiped my hard drive and have a dual boot of Win 10 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. My computer is an ASUS Vivobook with Intel® Core™ i7-8550U × 8 and 16 gigs of ram with about 100 gigs free on the Ubuntu partition.
Would you please help me find the problem?
enter image description here
ivnux@livnux-X411UA:~$ ls -l /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER
total 11352
drwxrwxr-x 2 livnux livnux     4096 Jan 19  2022 Docs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 livnux livnux    12011 Jan 19  2022 EULA.txt
drwxrwxr-x 9 livnux livnux     4096 Jan 19  2022 InstallData
-rw-rw-r-- 1 livnux livnux     2801 Jan 19  2022 libSwell.colortheme
lrwxrwxrwx 1 livnux livnux       51 Jun  5 21:50 libSwell.so -> /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/libSwell.so
drwxrwxr-x 4 livnux livnux     4096 Jan 19  2022 Plugins
-rwxrwxr-x 1 livnux livnux  1287536 Jan 19  2022 reamote-server
-rwxrwxr-x 1 livnux livnux 10133136 Jan 19  2022 reaper
-rwxrwxr-x 1 livnux livnux        0 Jun  5 21:13 reaper.ini
drwxrwxr-x 2 livnux livnux    12288 Jan 19  2022 Resources
drwxrwxr-x 4 livnux livnux     4096 Jun  5 21:09 WDL
-rw-rw-r-- 1 livnux livnux   153826 Jan 19  2022 whatsnew.txt



What are the actual errors you are getting? What version of reaper are you trying to install?

I don't know, I just press the app and nothing happens. Is there some way I could search for errors?

Latest version, straight from Reaper website. Version 7.16.

Not sure if reaper actually logs anything ... You can try starting reaper inside a terminal instead of clicking the shortcut, see if you get any helpful output.

I am not very well acquainted with the terminal. I mostly cut and paste from websites. Would prefer it all to be graphical... Online guides tell me to just type Reaper in Terminal but nothing happens.

What do you mean by "nothing happens"? I find it a bit hard to believe that your terminal doesn't output at least an error like "command not found".
What option did you pick when installing reaper from the install script? "Add desktop integration"? In that case, reaper binary should be installed under /home/your_username/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/reaper - try running that. You can also try just running reaper from the install script by pressing R.

I have Installed and added desktop integration. I tried R now and litteraly nothing happens and Terminal just closes!

Ok, so I tried some more. I can start Inkscape from terminal just typing 'inkscape'. When i type 'reaper' it says 'reaper: command not found' so somehow it must not have installed even though i did all of the above and I have an icon in my app drawer. I have a Reaper folder under 'home'.

This doesn't necessarily mean reaper was not installed - just that your system doesn't know where the reaper binary is. Try starting it with providing the absolute path inside your terminal, like mentioned in my previous comment (replace your_username, and directory names if needed):
./home/your_username/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/reaper.

/home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/reaper
Error loading '/home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/libSwell.so': /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/libSwell.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But i copied that path from 'files' and I can clearly see libSwell.so there

OK, this is probably the error that we've been looking for. Update your question with the output from this command: ls -l /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER

Ok, did that.
Thank you for helping me!

Your link is broken, i'm guessing. See the answer.

At first I thought you have a circular reference for your libSwell.so, but now I see that your link is pointing to this location:
libSwell.so -> /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/libSwell.so

Double check if the file exists at /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64 - I am guessing it does not.
It should be like this (provided that the file is inside your WDL subdirectory, where it's generated by default):
libSwell.so -> /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/WDL/WDL/swell/libSwell.so

To create this, first remove the current link:
rm /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/libSwell.so

Then create the link again. Double check where the libSwell file actually is - it should be under /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/WDL/WDL/swell/
ln -s /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/WDL/WDL/swell/libSwell.so /home/livnux/reaper/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER/libSwell.so

After that, start reaper again, and see if the error is resolved. If not, the link is probably broken.
Check the output:

Additional info:
to be able to run reaper from any directory by just typig in "reaper", you should add this directory to your "PATH" variable:
export PATH=$PATH:~/reaper_linux_x86_64/REAPER

If you want to make this change permanent, add this line to your ~/.bashrc file.

Frustratingly, in frustration, i ran uninstall-reaper.sh (from executable folder) and uninstalled it, deleted all folders. Then extracted from tar, sucessfully ran the executable, installed it and it now starts from app drawer. Somehow reinstalling it worked out. Still unsure what it fixed but it did.
Will go ahead and delete my numerous comments @amar
